# Matlab scatter using different color gradients per group

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I didn't find a way to plot scattered data (Lon X Lat X variable) classified in groups (>4), where the value of my variable in each group goes from 0.5 to 1. So far I did it in plain colors, no variation (color gradient) per group. I applied a FOR loop, one step per group, changing colors each step. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it's not working with `gscatter`, right?

Comment: So wasn't your approach using the for loop and different colormaps for each group not working? Thats the way to go. Please post the code you have.

Comment: In a certain way, your comment helped! gscatter did almost the same job the loop, except that I needed to convert my "cluster pertinence" (0 to 1 per group) variable into an integer cluster number (1-5 this case) in order to use as "group" parameter for gscatter.
That is why I need the color gradient or something alike to represent all grouping (once they don't overlap) in one graph instead of 5!
Anyway, thanks for the answer... still looking!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way around the one-colormap-per-figure limit would be to offset the data, so e.g. group 1 goes from 0.5 to 1, group 2 goes from 1.5 to 2, group 3 from 2.5 to 3 etc. then create a colormap that is the concatenation of all the gradients. That way each group 'indexes' into the correct region of the colormap and achieves the desired effect.

The alternative would be to bypass the indexed colormap and pre-generate a matrix with specific RGB values for each point, then pass that to `scatter()`. For total control there's the option of traversing the handles to get to the underlying patch objects and setting `CData` directly, but I'd try to get it done with an easier approach before going that far.